# Can't find bug in hash table copy constructor

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable, deep-copy

when performing a copy of hash tables using my copy constructor such as:

```
LPTable<int> hashtableCopy = hashtable;
```

the program crashes and I am unsure why. I have went through the debugger and it seems it knows what values it is receiving in the for loop, so I am confused as to what is happening, if it is a syntax/logical problem or what. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you. I will post what i have attempted so far.

**hash table with copy ctor**

```
template <class TYPE>
class LPTable :public Table<TYPE> {

    struct Record {
            TYPE data_;
            string key_;
            bool isDeleted = false;

            Record() {
                    key_ = "";
                    data_ = 0;
                    isDeleted = false;
            }

            Record(const string& key, const TYPE& data) {
                    key_ = key;
                    data_ = data;
                    isDeleted = false;
            }

    };

    Record** records_;   //the table
    int LargerMax;       // *1.35 max_
    int max_;           //capacity of the array
    int size_;          //current number of records held
    int MyHash(string key); // custom hash function 
    int numRecords() const { return this.size_; }
    bool isEmpty()         { return size_ = 0; }

public:
    LPTable(int maxExpected);
    LPTable(const LPTable& other);
    LPTable(LPTable&& other);
    virtual bool update(const string& key, const TYPE& value);
    virtual bool remove(const string& key);
    virtual bool find(const string& key, TYPE& value);
    virtual const LPTable& operator=(const LPTable& other);
    virtual const LPTable& operator=(LPTable&& other);
    virtual ~LPTable();
};
/* none of the code in the function definitions below are correct.  You   can replace what you need
*/
template <class TYPE>
LPTable<TYPE>::LPTable(int maxExpected) : Table<TYPE>() {
    LargerMax = maxExpected * 1.35;

    records_ = new Record*[LargerMax];  

    for (int i = 0; i < LargerMax; i++)
    {
            records_[i] = nullptr;
    }

    size_ = 0;
}

//copy ctor
template <class TYPE>
LPTable<TYPE>::LPTable(const LPTable<TYPE>& other) {


    records_ = new Record*[other.LargerMax];    

    for (int i = 0; i < other.LargerMax; i++)
    {
            while (other.records_[i] != nullptr)
            {
                    records_[i]->key_ = other.records_[i]->key_;
                    records_[i]->data_ = other.records_[i]->data_;
                    records_[i]->isDeleted = other.records_[i]->isDeleted;
            }
    }

}

template <class TYPE>
const LPTable<TYPE>& LPTable<TYPE>::operator=(const LPTable<TYPE>& other) 
{

    LPTable temp(other);
    std::swap(temp.records_, records_);
    std::swap(temp.max_, max_);
    std::swap(temp.size_, size_);
    return *this;

}


template <class TYPE>
const LPTable<TYPE>& LPTable<TYPE>::operator=(LPTable<TYPE>&& other) {
    return *this;

}
template <class TYPE>
LPTable<TYPE>::~LPTable() {

     delete[] records_;
}
```

Comment: `while (other.records_[i] != nullptr)` - you don't change `other.records_` in that loop, so it's probably infinite

Comment: @Alexander Lapenkov i also tried with a for loop and gave me same crash

Comment: i think it might be because of a default ctor mishap somehow on initializtion

Comment: You are only allocating an array of pointers here: `records_ = new Record*[other.LargerMax];`. They are pointing to random places since you haven't allocated the memory for each `Record` they point to. So you need to add `records_[i] = new Record();` in the loop before you assign values.

Comment: @ kjpus how shoudl i set up a default Record ctor for this? or do i need to since i have the 2 argument one?

Answer (score 0):

You never set `LargerMax`, `max_`, or `size_` in your copy constructor.  (You don't set `max_` in the constructor taking `int`, either.)

When you copy `other.records_`, you're not allocating space for the records you need.  If the pointer in `other.records_` is `nullptr`, just set that as the new pointer value in `records_[i]`, otherwise set that to a new record allocated using the Records copy constructor.  Replace the `while` loop with

```
records_[i] = other.records_[i] == nullptr ? nullptr : new Record(other.records_[i])
```